# Displacement-Length scaling relationship on extraterrestrial faults

Tags: planetary-science, structural-geology, crust

Faults on Earth share a similar displacement/length ratio of around 0.03 which scales from very small faults to very large faults. Would this apply to faults on other planets and if so, are there any examples?

Answer (score -2):

Your assumption is wrong (Lathrop et al., 2022).

[image]

The image is coming from Lathrop et al (2022) ["Displacement/Length Scaling Relationships for Normal Faults; a Review, Critique, and Revised Compilation"](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/feart.2022.907543/full) which I invite you to read, for a review on the topic.

Said this, it is likely that extraterrestrial fault will have "similar" behavior.

Comment: It sure looks like 0.03 is a reasonable estimate for the typical ratio of D/L in figure A?  There's certainly a range, but still a real clear consistency to D/L from small lengths to large?  So you may want to explain more how the OP is supposed to be wrong with his assumption so people get a rough idea without reading the paper, as otherwise I don't think there's anything convincing from what you say (said as someone with only very limited geological background)

Comment: @JeopardyTempest r^2 = 0.85, for D/L=0.3 ... I will addthe  excerpt from the publication. Please note the plot is log-log, so the spread is huuuuuge.

Comment: I think you mean .03, yes?  As .3 would be above the second line down, which would seem to be rather off center?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest yes, sure, typo, r^2=0.85 for D/L 0.03 ... cannot correct anymore and did not find the time to expand my answer.